# Recycling JDBC connections after some time

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have an application using an Oracle RAC database. To execute maintenance tasks on the database nodes, I'd like to migrate all connections away from database node 1, then switch the node off for maintenance.

What I would like is to make sure that database connections dont stay open for more than X minutes. When a DB node is put in maintenance, the connections opened on that node will be closed after at most X minutes and recreated on the other.

The connection pool used is common-dbcp, with the intention to move to tomcat-jdbc. For both pool, I cant see a configuration option to force recycling the connections after some time. Am I missing something ? Or is this not a standard option ?

Comment: i dont think its an option. you can use the test on borrow but its expesive. maybe you can add an option to destroy the entire pool and re-create it and call that when you take the system down for maintenence

Comment: Test on borrow will not help as connections already opened on a node are still valid. Destroying the entire pool would break currently opened connection which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: i think u can destroy it nicely, so that connections not in the pool are destroyed after they are returned

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [tomcat-jdbc documentation](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html), I see that there is a maxAge parameter that does almost what I need. I'll run some checks next week to confirm and will update this answer to reflect my findings.

Comment: How about the result? :)